# ¿Porque seda esta excepción com.itextpdf.tool.xml.PipelineException: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline can't find its own context

Tags: java, itext

Estoy generando un PDF apartir de un HTML con itextPdf V.5.5.11 usando la clase XMLParser al que le pongo un header apartir de HTML por pagina con el método onStartPage de la interfaz PdfPageEvent, todo el PDF se crea bien pero tengo una duda ¿Porque en la linea me sale este error com.itextpdf.tool.xml.PipelineException: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline can't find its own context en la linea //Aquí excepción producida?

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 10, 10);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, out);
String HTML = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"><title>HTML to PDF</title></head><body><span>code</span></body></html>";

int margen_left_base = 280-("HTML to PDF".length() *2);
    writer.setPageEvent(new PdfPageEvent() {
        @Override
        public void onStartPage(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document) {
            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null){
                @Override
                public HtmlPipelineContext clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                    return super.clone();
                }
            };
            htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
            Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true),
                    new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(pdfWriter, document)));
            try {
                new XMLParser(new XMLWorker(pipeline, true){}).parse(new ByteArrayInputStream("<h3>header</h3>".getBytes()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document) {}
        @Override
        public void onEndPage(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document) {}
        @Override
        public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document) {}
        @Override
        public void onParagraph(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document, float v) {}
        @Override
        public void onParagraphEnd(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document, float v) {}
        @Override
        public void onChapter(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document, float v, Paragraph paragraph) {}
        @Override
        public void onChapterEnd(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document, float v) {}
        @Override
        public void onSection(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document, float v, int i, Paragraph paragraph) {}
        @Override
        public void onSectionEnd(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document, float v) {}
        @Override
        public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document, Rectangle rectangle, String s) {}
    });
    doc.open();
HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null){
    @Override
    public HtmlPipelineContext clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
};

htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
Pipeline<?> pipeline =  new CssResolverPipeline(XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true), new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer)));
try {
    new XMLParser(new XMLWorker(pipeline, true)).parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(HTML.getBytes()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);//Aquí excepción producida
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
doc.close();
```

Comment: la carpeta compartida esta en la red o ya lo mapeaste como disco de red en tu sistema operativo?

Comment: creo que si ... intenta eso primero y valida si te aparece en la listas de discos ...